# ICloud shows 3Gb messages, but top conversations shows 0kb

Tags: icloud, messages-in-icloud

I can’t back up my iPhone. I’ve removed many of my videos and photos from my iPhone and from my messages, but iCloud shows the largest storage is messages - 3Gb. When I click on messages, however, top  conversations shows 0kb. How do I reclaim my space?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try going to Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage? There it will give you a breakdown of which apps are using the most storage and give you direct ways to review and delete the files.

A restart may also help the system recognize that those files have been removed, but someone with more technical knowledge than I may inform me that is not a necessary action.

Comment: I wonder whether this is actually a bug… Yesterday we were having a similar fight with an iPhone that claims 10GB needed for backup, yet nothing in storage agrees with that. I eventually just gave up & backed it to the Mac. Another phone, equally full, takes a mere 1.8GB to backup online. [No photos or music are set to backup, all held locally]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that showed that I had two conversations that were 600Mb and 400Mb, so there’s 1Gb right there. I don’t want to delete these. Is there a quick way to save them to a file or remove older messages? (I know I can manually go through and remove individual messages, but that would take forever.)